# Unable to get values from form in controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, form-submit

I have an MVC 4 website (.NET 4.5) wherein I want to re-direct the user to a very simple login page if they are trying to gain access to the High Resolution Photos (Hrp) section of the website. I have setup the routes and they seem to be working fine, i.e. The user is routed to the 'Index' page or the 'Login' page. However, when I receive the data in my 'Login' method in the HrpController the username and password fields are null even though I filled them in on the form.

The logical flow of the application should be as follows:

1. User goes to the Index page (/Hrp), if the user is not logged on, they will be given the Login form
2. The user fills in the Login form and submits it to HrpController.Login (/Hrp/Login)
3. The HrpController.Login method should get the username and password and verify it against  hard-coded values (I understand that this is very weak security, but it is a rewrite of existing code and I am not at liberty to change the mechanism)
4. If the username and password match with what was entered on the form the user will be given the Hrp Index page (/Hrp)
5. If the username or password do not match, then send the user back to the Login page (/Hrp/Login)

I'm not sure why the username and password values are null, rather than containing the values that the user filled in on the form. Any help is highly appreciated.

Routes:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Hrp",
          url: "Hrp/",
          defaults: new { controller = "Hrp", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HrpLogin",
            url: "Hrp/Login/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Hrp", action = "Login" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HrpDetails",
            url: "Hrp/Details/{id}/",
            defaults: new { controller = "Hrp", action = "Details",
                            id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The form:

```
@using MyApp.App_Code;

@model MyApp.App_Code.Models.HrpUser


@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Hrp", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login failed. Check your login details.");
    <div>
         <div id="content" class="content">
            <section id="article">
                <div class="cont orangeTopBorder">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Login</legend>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.username)
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.username)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.username)
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(u => u.password)
                        </div>
                        <div class="editor-field">
                            @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.password)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.password)
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </fieldset>
                    <div class="footerarticle">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
        if (username == "yourname" && password == "yourpassword")
        {
            SetHrpLogonAccepted();

            // Load Hrp object here, then show the main Hrp page

            return RedirectToAction("Index", hrp);
        }
        else
        {
            return View("Login");
        }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (IsHrpLogonAccepted() == false)
        {
            return View("Login");
        }
        else
        {
               // Load Hrp object here, then show the main Hrp page

                return View("Index", hrp);
        }
   }
```

HrpUser:

```
    public class HrpUser
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
```

Helper methods:

```
    private bool IsHrpLogonAccepted()
    {
        return Session["HrpLogonAccepted"] != null;
    }

    private void SetHrpLogonAccepted()
    {
        Session["HrpLogonAccepted"] = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your login ActionResult to this:

```
public ActionResult Login(HrpUser loginModel)
{
    if (loginModel.username == "yourname" && loginModel.password == "yourpassword")
    {
        SetHrpLogonAccepted();

        // Load Hrp object here, then show the main Hrp page

        return RedirectToAction("Index", hrp);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Login");
    }
}
```

Comment: I dropped in your code, however loginModel.username and loginModel.password are null, just like before.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but here is the fiddler trace (marked up). POST http://www.[ my web site ].localhost/Hrp/Login HTTP/1.1
Host: www.[ my web site ].localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.[ my web site ].localhost/Hrp/
Cookie: [cookie was here]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 29

username=afdg&password=asdfds

Answer (score 0):

The form was getting submitted as a POST to Hrp/Login and the browser was doing a 301 redirect to Hrp/Login/. During this redirect it sent the data as a GET rather than a POST, therefore it was able to route to my HrpController.Login method because it was not decorated with the [HttpPost] attribute, by default it is a GET.

To work around this I am now decorating with the [HttpPost] attribute.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Login(HrpUser loginModel)
```

I am also adding a slash to "Login/":

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login/", "Hrp", FormMethod.Post))
```

Since I am having to do this hack, I think that I will see about doing a redirection such that my form is located at /Hrp/Login and possibly I can get rid of the hack by just using:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

Comment: Further note: I was able to use return RedirectToAction("Login"); to call the GET version of my Login method that now renders the view.   [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View("Login");
        }. This allowed me to just use @using (Html.BeginForm()) on the form.